# Couldn't install inside Windows 8

Tags: 12.10

I've boot with Ubuntu 12.10 boot able disk. I've selected Install inside windows option. PC has been restarted. Then My windows 8 started normally. But, the installation didn't started.

Comment: What option did you choose for installation? and did you leave the CD in the drive when the system was restarted?

Comment: It might help to mention what sort of system it is - did it come with windows 8 preinstalled, or did you install it yourself?

Answer (score 2):

To install Ubuntu from within windows, you need to use Wubi.

To use Wubi, just download it from [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer?distro=wubi&release=&bits=).

For morre info take a look at [Installing Ubuntu from within Windows](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi).

To install Along side Windows, just choose that option when you get to the installation type screen.

For Wubi installation instructions click [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wubi)

For other installation methods click [Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

Answer (score 1):

The following things may help you-

1. Try resetting your boot order. If the hard drive boots before you disk, the OS is only going to find Windows 8 and hence run it. Ubuntu must be visible to the OS before Windows is. To change the boot order is not tough. As the computer starts, a black screen usually with name of the manufacturer shows up. In this screen is information related on how to enter the boot menu. However if you can't read it, you'll have to try one of the following keys which usually allows you to enter the boot- Esc, F1-F12 or Delete. Once you are in, there will be a tab in the menu saying boot. Change the boot order in there to put the CD/DVD drive before Hard disk. I faced this problem myself when I formatted Windows 7 to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my desktop. The instructions at the bottom of the boot menu will help you on how to navigate between windows and how to set the boot order. As all boot chips are programmed differently from their manufacturers, there is not going to be much help there from us.
2. If, however, this doesn't work, then- check if the DVD or CD you have has Ubuntu installed in it properly. After burning, the disk should have 700+ MB occupied. This is the simplest method to check if the burn was complete or not. Try using the same DVD/CD as a Live CD on some other PC.
3. Although I don't have any proper link to backup this statement, I've heard (elsewhere) that people were complaining about Windows 8 blocking other OS to be installed alongside it and some said that Microsoft will ask you to buy a key from it to unlock the loader to install other OS alongside Windows 8 in dual boot. Maybe its true. Maybe its not. I don't know for sure

Comment: "buy a key" no. Secureboot may be an issue here, but that can be turned off in the bios or otherwise circumvented at the user level bu design.

Comment: Microsoft isn't forcing laptop and desktop makers to ban Linux, though it's giving them the tools to do so.  See this article [Microsoft Bans Linux/Android Dual-Booting on Windows 8 ARM Devices](http://www.dailytech.com/Microsoft+Bans+LinuxAndroid+DualBooting+on+Windows+8+ARM+Devices/article23785.htm)